# Remove antivirus from startup via command prompt (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, boot

How from the windows command prompt can I tell my machine (windows 7) to not load my antivirus software (Symantec if that matters) automatically the next time I boot it up? Assume I can't open any other windows; just the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it from the command prompt?

Why not the proper way – to un-install or prevent from loading it?  Since it is on the startup ini, you should remove the app from there.

If you wish to have a solution, then make a batch script, call it e.g `startup-script.bat`, put it on startup folder. The script should run a [`taskkill`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) command to kill the norton process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your AV intact in your system as an on demand scanner but do not want it to run real-time, you should first RTFM! There you can find your AV's command-line options. This is safer way. I do not recommend killing the AV process.